# Using Streams filter a list of maximum values based on Conditions

Tags: java-8

I have a list like below with custom Object, i need to filter out the maximum stake values , based on customer id and betOfferId, but customer id should not repeat(duplicate) , basically for a particular betofferid i want to get a list of highest stake values customer wise and limit it for 20 customers max for a particular stake.

For eg , for the below list if i given betofferid as 999 , i need to get like this, since there are 2 customers , this is fine. 
{
        "customerId": 12345,
        "betOfferId": 999,
        "stake": 9000
    } and {
        "customerId": 1234,
        "betOfferId": 999,
        "stake": 8500
    }

### Below given the Stakes

{
        "customerId": 1234,
        "betOfferId": 888,
        "stake": 4500
    }

```
{
    "customerId": 12345,
    "betOfferId": 999,
    "stake": 9000
},
{
    "customerId": 12345,
    "betOfferId": 999,
    "stake": 8000
},
{
    "customerId": 1234,
    "betOfferId": 888,
    "stake": 8500
},
{
    "customerId": 1234,
    "betOfferId": 888,
    "stake": 7500
},
{
    "customerId": 1234,
    "betOfferId": 999,
    "stake": 7500
},
{
    "customerId": 1234,
    "betOfferId": 999,
    "stake": 7500
},
{
    "customerId": 1234,
    "betOfferId": 999,
    "stake": 8500
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about it:

```
List<T> result = source.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getOfferId() == offerId)
            .collect(toMap(T::getCustomerId,
                    Function.identity(),
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(T::getStake))))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(T::getStake))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.stream().limit(20))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- retains only objects where their offer is if equal to the supplied `offerId`.
- customer ids do not repeat as you've mentioned.
- gets the highest stake values customer wise.
- and limited to 20 customers for a *particular stake*.

---

breakdown of the stream pipeline:

at this point, we now have distinct objects by customer id and the highest stake values customer wise.

```
source.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getOfferId() == offerId)
            .collect(toMap(T::getCustomerId,
                    Function.identity(),
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(T::getStake))))
```

now we limit it for 20 customers max for a particular stake.

```
.values()
.stream()
.collect(groupingBy(T::getStake))
.values()
.stream()
.flatMap(x -> x.stream().limit(20))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `T` is the class containing the `customerId`, `stake` etc...

[**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/gbn2Nk)